# How to compute the following integral $I_{\alpha,\beta}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

We have the following identity (see Bateman, H. (1953). Higher Transcendental Functions [Volumes I], p. 25.) 
$$(*)\quad \Gamma(s)\, \zeta(s,\nu) = \int_{0}^{1} x^{\nu-1} \,(1-x)^{-1}  \Bigr(\log 1/x\Big)^{s-1} \, dx; \quad  \Re e (s)>1,\Re e (\nu)>0,$$
where $\Gamma(s)$ is the Gamma function and $\zeta(s,\nu)$ is the generalized zeta function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html

Now, I would like compute the following
$$I_{\alpha,\beta} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{\alpha} \,(1-x)^{-2}  \Bigr(\log 1/x\Big)^{\beta} \, dx; \quad  \alpha>0,\,  -1<\beta<0.$$
Thank you in advance

Comment: I would like compute $I_{\alpha, \beta}$

Comment: isn't this just integration by parts? $v'=(1-x)^{-1},u=\log(1/x)^{\beta-1}x^{\alpha}$

Comment: @tired, no, it  is not the integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

Notice: 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[x^a(1-x)^{-1}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta}\right] &= ax^{a-1}(1-x)^{-1}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta} \\
&\quad + x^a(1-x)^{-2}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta} \\
&\quad + \beta x^{a-1}(1-x)^{-1}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta-1}
\end{aligned}
and hence
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 x^a(1-x)^{-2}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta} \,dx &= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx} \left[x^a(1-x)^{-1}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta}\right]\, dx \\
&\quad - a\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{-1}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta}\, dx \\
&\quad - \beta \int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{-1}\left(\log \frac{1}{x} \right)^{\beta-1} \, dx
\end{aligned}
It seems to me that the right hand side of this last equality is solvable (either by the fundamental theorem of calc, or by your identity above).

Comment: Thank's. But, we can not apply the identity $(*)$, because $-1<\beta<0$ in my case for the integral $I_{\alpha,\beta}$.

Comment: For this parameters your integral is simply divergent